# Training WGAN-GP: weird generated images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I'm studying GANs, and atm I'm trying to implement a WGAN-GP, based on codes presented in books and Keras tutorials. I was able to train a regular GAN as shown [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/paulaceccon/deep-learning-studies/blob/main/notebooks/generative_models/gans/dcgan.ipynb). When adapting that code to be a WGAN-GP, I'm getting weird generated images though:

[image]

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. This is the definition of the WGAN-GP:

```
class WGAN_GP(Model):
    """Implements a Wasserstein GAN with Gradient Penalty"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        discriminator,
        generator,
        latent_dim,
        discriminator_extra_steps=3,
        gp_weight=10.0,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.generator = generator
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.d_steps = discriminator_extra_steps
        self.gp_weight = gp_weight

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, d_loss_fn, g_loss_fn):
        super().compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.d_loss_fn = d_loss_fn
        self.g_loss_fn = g_loss_fn

    def gradient_penalty(self, batch_size, real_images, fake_images):
        """
        Calculates the gradient penalty.

        This loss is calculated on an interpolated image
        and added to the discriminator loss.
        """
        # Get the interpolated image
        alpha = tf.random.normal([batch_size, 1, 1, 1], 0.0, 1.0)
        diff = fake_images - real_images
        interpolated = real_images + alpha * diff

        with tf.GradientTape() as gp_tape:
            gp_tape.watch(interpolated)
            # 1. Get the discriminator output for this interpolated image.
            pred = self.discriminator(interpolated)

        # 2. Calculate the gradients w.r.t to this interpolated image.
        grads = gp_tape.gradient(pred, [interpolated])[0]
        # 3. Calculate the norm of the gradients.
        norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grads), axis=[1, 2, 3]))
        gp = tf.reduce_mean((norm - 1.0) ** 2)
        return gp

    def train_step(self, real_images) -> dict:
        # 1. Train the discriminator
        # The original paper recommends training
        # the discriminator for `x` more steps (typically 5) as compared to
        # one step of the generator. 
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
        for i in range(self.d_steps):
          # Sample random points in the latent space
          # and decode them to fake images
          random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))
          generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)
          generated_logits = self.discriminator(generated_images)
          real_logits = self.discriminator(real_images)

          with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
              d_cost = self.d_loss_fn(real_logits, generated_logits)
              # Calculate the gradient penalty
              gp = self.gradient_penalty(batch_size, generated_images, real_images)
              # Add the gradient penalty to the original discriminator loss
              d_loss = d_cost + gp * self.gp_weight
          grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
          self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
              zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
          )

        # 2. Train the generator
        # Sample random points in the latent space and calculate the loss
        # (note that we should *not* update the weights of the discriminator)!
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(self.generator(random_latent_vectors))
            g_loss = self.g_loss_fn(predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))

        return {
            "d_loss": d_loss,
            "g_loss": g_loss,
        }

# Define the loss functions for the discriminator,
# which should be (fake_loss - real_loss).
# We will add the gradient penalty later to this loss function.
def discriminator_loss(real_img, fake_img):
    real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(real_img)
    fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(fake_img)
    return fake_loss - real_loss


# Define the loss functions for the generator.
def generator_loss(fake_img):
    return -tf.reduce_mean(fake_img)
```

The full code can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/paulaceccon/deep-learning-studies/blob/main/notebooks/generative_models/gans/wgan_gp.ipynb).
I've tried changing the network, adjusting the lr, but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your generator is suffering from mode collapse; it has found one (or a small number) of images that fool the discriminator every time. From this answer: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51276/gan-am-i-seeing-mode-collapse-common-fixes-not-working.

"Be sure that your learning rate is small enough. My first problem was a large learning rate (I used 0.001 with Adam, then realized that my model only works with something small like 0.0002)."

"Make sure learning is happening. Track the loss values over time and make sure they make sense. There shouldn't be any spikes in loss values, else something is wrong."

Unfortunately, tuning GANs can be more of an art than a science, so play around with hyperparameters and carefully not what works and what doesn't. Hope this helps!